# How to overload operator in non-class package?

Tags: perl, operator-overloading

In my situation I don't need warnings `Use of uninitialized value in string` while comparing string equality. So I tought that instead silencing all such warnings in the scope with `no warnings 'uninitialized'` would be better to overload `eq`-operator with my own subroutine, like:

```
use overload 'eq' => \&undefined_equal;

sub undefined_equal {
  my ( $left, $right ) = @_;
  no warnings 'uninitialized';

  if ( $left eq $right ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, `overload`ing does not work, because according to the docs, `overload` is meant to use with classes, but I have plain procedural packages.

So I did try with overloading built-in functions, like:

```
package REeq;
use strict; use warnings; use 5.014;

BEGIN {
  use Exporter ();
  @REeq::ISA         = qw( Exporter );
  @REeq::EXPORT      = qw( eq );
}

sub eq {
  my ( $left, $right ) = @_;
  no warnings 'uninitialized';

  if ( $left CORE::eq $right ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
1;
```

I can call my `eq` but can't use it as operator.

I need it because I want instead

```
if ( defined $some_scalar && $some_scalar eq 'literal string' ){
....
}
```

to use just

```
if ( $some_scalar eq 'literal string' ){
....
}
```

How could I achieve my goal?

Comment: Why not just not use variables that aren't defined?

Comment: @Shawn because there are situations when variables may or may not be defined. In my situation I need to compare value from DB table, which may have value or `NULL`. In my situation `NULL` is not equal with values I compare with, so I need to suppress this warning here.

Comment: You can test it for defined-ness before trying to use it.

Comment: @Shawn I can. As you may see from two last examples above, my current routine is to combine testing definedness with comparing, but point of my question is: can I create my own `eq`-operator which does not need this. Like we have `//` operator for boolean-checking besides `||`. Do you see `//` redundant?

Comment: I don't see how to write it as an operator, as `eq` seems to have no prototype (`prototype q(CORE::eq)` returns `undef`).  I'd be content with using my own function (`is_equal` etc), in which case I can also tell from across the room that it's that special case which allows `undef`s (so when I use the actual `eq` it'll yell for 'undef', as expected)

Comment: @zdim I thought about using own utility like `is_equal` (and seems I will use something like that), but wanted to see if I could implement infix-operator behavior in easy way. XS is not in my toolbox for now

Comment: @w.k Yeah, I got that -- I meant to say that I don't think it can be done and so that I would then settle for an utility (which also has advantages).  Then it's nice that we got from ikegami that one needs to crawl into the engine compartment for it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the behaviour of `eq` is possible, but it requires writing an XS modules that creates an op checker that replaces the code `perl` executes for the `eq` ops in scope. This is the approach used by `no autovivification;`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you can - I haven't tried this but [the perl monks have](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=481747)

> sure, if you see it that way... you just have to bless your variable,
> just like you did with your Number-package.

```
use overload ...;
my $n = bless {number => 23}, "main";
print $n >> 2;
```

> i think that's not what you want, just wanted to make clear that it's
> not a problem of the package name but that you must have a blessed
> object.

---

Edit: taking zdim's onboard...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use overload 'eq' => \&undefined_equal;

sub undefined_equal {
  my ( $left, $right ) = @_;
  no warnings 'uninitialized';

  if ( ${$left} eq $right ) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

my $a = "abcde";
my $n = bless \$a, "main";


print "a eq undef -->";
print $a eq undef;

print "<--\nn eq undef -->";
print $n eq undef;
print "<--\n";
```

which gives

```
$ perl overload.pl
Use of uninitialized value in string eq at overload.pl line 20.
a eq undef --><--
n eq undef -->0<--
```

Don't forget the double `$$` in the sub or you disappear into recursion. And the scalar reference for `bless` as you can only bless references, it seems

It still has a `bless` but hey

Comment: Yes, but that's not what they want, as it says in the question.  That makes it work on objects of the class where overloading is done; they're asking about doing it so that it works for any old variable.

Comment: Your solution makes code more complicated, my goal is to simplify workflow. Changing `CORE::eq` with my version would have a minor impact on code readability, adding all the mangling with blessed references blurs intention. Thank you for your effort to find a way to a solution!

Comment: Nice that you added a full program to show a way to overload.  But as for the question itself, the program proves the point -- it is precisely `$a eq undef` that they'd like to make work without warnings, not to have to make an object (`$n`) out of each variable first.